# How to wake up a sleeping thread from the main Thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have a capture program which in addition do capturing data and writing it into a file also prints some statistics.The function that prints the statistics

```
static void report(void)
{
         /*Print statistics*/
}
```

is called roughly every second using an ALARM that expires every second.So The program is like

```
void capture_program()
{
       pthread_t report_thread

            while()
            {
                     if(pthread_create(&report_thread,NULL,report,NULL)){
                            fprintf(stderr,"Error creating reporting thread! \n");
                     }

                     /*
                        Capturing code
                        --------------
                        --------------
                      */
                      if(doreport)
                             /*wakeup the sleeping thread.*/

            }
}

void *report(void *param)
{
       //access some register from hardware
       //sleep for a second 

}
```

The expiry of the timer sets the `doreport` flag.If this flag is set `report()` is called which clears the flag.

How do I wake up the sleeping thread (that runs the report()) when the timer goes off in the main thread?

Comment: What you are looking for is some kind of [event-signaling mechanism](http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_28.html). Use that in combination with your flag (and look for spurious wakeups in the linked document to learn why).

Comment: Consider throwing what you have away and then just using the `timer_create` family of calls instead of `alarm`.  They allow you specify a specific thread (or create a new thread each time) to direct the signal to.  That is exactly what you want to do.  Otherwise you have to block signals in particular threads to force them to be delivered to the one you want or, alternatively, go down some rabbit hole of condvars and the like.  Bite the bullet now and do it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I wake up the sleeping thread (that runs the report()) when the
>   timer goes off in the main thread?

I think a [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) is the mechanism you are looking for.  Have the report-thread block on the condition variable, and the main thread signal the condition variable whenever you want the report-thread to wake up (see the link for more detailed instructions).

Answer (score 9):

You can sleep a thread using sigwait, and then signal that thread to wake up with pthread_kill.  Kill sounds bad, but it doesn't kill the thread, it sends a signal.  This method is very fast.  It was much faster than condition variables.  I am not sure it is easier, harder, safer or more dangerous, but we needed the performance so we went this route.

in startup code somewhere:

```
sigemptyset(&fSigSet);
sigaddset(&fSigSet, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&fSigSet, SIGSEGV);
```

to sleep, the thread does this:

```
int nSig;
sigwait(&fSigSet, &nSig);
```

to wake up (done from any other thread)

```
pthread_kill(pThread, SIGUSR1);
```

or to wake up you could do this:

```
tgkill(nPid, nTid, SIGUSR1);
```

Our code calls this on the main thread before creating child threads.  I'm not sure why this would be required.

```
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &fSigSet, NULL);
```

Comment: `pthread_sigmask()` prevents a crash on receipt of SIGUSR1.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when coding an UDP chat server: there is a thread_1 that only works when an alarm interruption (timeout to see if the client is still alive) OR another thread_2 (this thread meets client requests) signals arrives. What I did was put this thread_1 to sleep (`sleep(n*TICK_TIMER)`, where TICK_TIMER is the alarm expiration value, n is some integer >1), and wake up this thread with `SIGALRM` signal. [See sleep() doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html)

The alarm handler ( to use this you have to init it: "signal(SIGALRM, tick_handler); alarm(5);")

```
void tick_handler(){tick_flag++; alarm(5); }
```

will send a `SIGALRM` when timeout occurs.

And the command to wake this sleep thread_1 from another thread_2 is:

```
    pthread_kill(X,SIGALRM);
```

where X is a `pthread_t` type. If your thread_1 is your main thread, you can get this number by `pthread_t X = pthread_self();`