# pthread_kill vs pthread_cond_signal for pausing/resuming a thread on a specific point

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, mutex

This request is about PThreads and using conditions or signals to pause/resume a continuous cycle worker thread.

A while ago, I came into this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945651/6421961

Basically, user johnnycrash uses **sigwait()** to get a thread into a pause state (waiting for external wakening) and **pthread_kill(thread_id, USR1)** to signal the thread into waking up. He claims it to be faster than using the *mutex+condition* construct and it appears to be less complex. I am developing a piece of software that would indeed require a thread to sleep until signaled and return to sleep after doing work in an infinite cycle (the eater of a feeder-eater paradigm).
I am using this to have a separate thread waiting for the conclusion of worker threads. In my current implementation, worker threads add their handles to a list protected by a mutex, signal the waiting thread with pthread_kill and finish with pthread_join.

My questions are all related:

1. How valid is it to actually use **pthread_kill()**+**sigwait()** instead of mutex+condition?
2. In case it is an acceptable solution, what pitfalls/race conditions
   should one be aware of?
3. Would it be better to use **pthread_sigqueue()** instead of **pthread_kill()**? Would it actually be able catch signals sent while **sigwait()** is not running and immediately process them as soon as **sigwait()** is called?
4. Last question, derived from some contradicting information I found: Will different threads both paused with **sigwait()** expecting **USR1** be able to be signaled independently, or will only one of them be able to actually catch the signal regardless of which one was signaled?

Comment: What about semaphores?  Using `sem_post()`/`sem_wait()` is even simpler than using signals.

Comment: I updated my question to provide more accurate information. How efficient would the semaphores be when comparing with the alternative constructs?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer points `1` and `4`.

1. `pthread_kill()` + `sigqueue()` and `mutex+condition` they both have their own purposes. When you're working with data (i.e. global variable) which is used by multiple threads in that case `mutex` are more appropriate. But, when you're waiting for an external event (like. network packet) and want to signal your thread based on that event `pthread_kill()` is more appropriate.
2. It depends how the signal (`USR1`) was sent. If it was sent using `pthread_kill()` or `pthread_sigqueue()` you can specify which thread you're sending that signal to, the only difference is with `pthread_sigqueue()` - you can send an additional information with the signal. You can also send signal to specific pid or group-wise signal sending using `kill()`. So, it largely depends on your need.

Comment: I have been trying to find the source (it was actually another thread here on stackoverflow), of someone categorically stating that pthread_kill doesn't really care which thread it sends the signal to, that if two threads are waiting for the same signal, any one thread can catch it, which I found quite odd.
I have updated my question to reflect a more detailed explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. I am hoping to use the best implementation possible for that use case.